# Set number of decimal places - PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell, script

So I'm building up a PowerShell script, and I wish to set the number of decimal places on a "Number" column. However, I can't seem to find the property necessary to do so. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldnumber.displayformat.aspx) is should be the `DisplayFormat` property that I'm trying to set, however, intelisense isn't giving me that as an option. Here's my code:

```
$fieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Number
$list.Fields.Add($fieldName, $fieldType, $fieldRequired)
$field = $list.Fields[$fieldName]
```

I would want to write another line, something like:

```
$field.DisplayFormat = 1
```

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of grappling with this, it seems all I needed was to set with a string value, as such what worked for me was:

`$fieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Number
 $list.Fields.Add($fieldName, $fieldType, $fieldRequired)
 $field = $list.Fields[$fieldName]
 $field.DisplayFormat = "OneDecimal"`

A learning point I picked up along the way however, using:

```
$fieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Number
```

Does not appear to be the same as using:

```
$fieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldNumber]
```

Although I haven't as yet got to the bottom as to why, hopefully this will help someone

Answer (score 3):

Try as below

```
$fieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Number
$field = $customList.Fields.Add("FieldName",$fieldType,$false)
$newfield = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldNumber]$customList.Fields[$field]
$customList.Fields[$newfield].DisplayFormat = SPNumberFormatTypes.OneDecimal
$customList.Fields[$newfield].Update()
```

Comment: On the line: $newfield = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldNumber]$customList.Fields[$field]. I am getting the error: Add-ListFields : Cannot convert the "TestColumn" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldText" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldNumber".

Comment: Make sure you are using proper field internal name. The error message is obvious.

Comment: Yes I realise. My $fieldType is exactly how you have typed above

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is as below:

```
$field.DisplayFormat = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPNumberFormatTypes]::NoDecimal
```